# how resolve 'Cannot resolve com.sun:tools:1.5' in maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

i am installed jdk 16 and import module and when clean install maven this error show:
Cannot resolve com.sun:tools:1.5

i searched about this problem and i understand that problem from tools.jar but i have not this file in jdk path in lib directory.

Comment: The issue is that this does not exist anymore since JDK8 which means you have to cleanup your build and dependencies which are using that ...in particular why is it needed... This is a usual dependencies in the old days (before JDK8)...

Comment: @khmarbaise i am not owner of project and i developer of it...i can not clean up it..what to do now?:((

Comment: Use an older JDK version, like 1.8 to build it (instead of JDK 16).

Comment: @CrazyCoder  can i install jdk 8 and just this project use it?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple JDK versions installed on the system and configure your projects  to use whatever versions they need.

Comment: Much better migrate that project...there is no way around that... that will cause more issues the longer you wait... even if you are not the owner..tell the owners to migrate that project to more recent versions...